# OpenDA in Python

Tags: python, calibration

I'm working on automating the calibration of a modelling software written in ANSI-C, it also has an interface/wrapper in Python. I just wanted to know if there is a way I can implement the OpenDA interface to this software. I'm good with python, but not very good in C/C++.

Comment: According to the site OpenDA has interfaces for C/C++, Java, and 
Fortran77/90.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I want to know if there is a pythonic interface to it Or at least if it's under development.